# Gdal Translate with scaling option in C#

Tags: gdal, c#, gdal-translate

I am trying to scale an image with Gdal using Gdal.wrapper_GDALTranslate. However, I have the options input for the scaling incorrectly formatted. The error I receive is "Too many command options 'scale=0 10000'".

Here is my code for the options variable:

```
string[] options = new string[]
{
    "of=PNG",
    "ot=BYTE",
    "scale=0 10000"
};
```

In the GDAL help for translate, https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html,it says that scale should be input like this `-scale [<src_min> <src_max> [<dst_min> <dst_max>]]`
I have also tried `"scale=[0 10000]"`, but receive the same error. Any ideas how I should format the 'scale' option for translate in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Should be formatted like this

```
string[] options = new string[]
{
    "-of","PNG",
    "-ot","BYTE",
    "-scale","0 10000"
};
```